# How can I get an LLVM Backend to generate function calls for mul instructions?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, backend

I'm trying to write a back-end for an ISA that does not have a multiply instruction, so multiplies need to be done with a loop of adds.

I am following [this guide.](https://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMBackend.html#audience)

I tried simply not defining any multiplies in the InstrInfo.td files, but this just causes it to fail when it reaches it. 
It's a completely 1:1 translation, so is there a way that I can just tell the compiler to replace any mul instruction with Multiply() fucntion call if I have it written somewhere?

Comment: RISC-V RV32I base ISA doesn't have multiply instructions. You could look at its backend.

Answer (score 2):

Every architecture comes with some limitations.

If an operation or operation of specific type is not supported by the architecture, then they can be set to `expand` in LLVM. The code generator will turn them to either `libcalls` or break them into smaller supported operations.

These expansion call can be found in `XXXISelLowering.cpp`

```
setOperationAction(ISD::FDIV, MVT::f32, Expand);
```

For the example above, F32 Div will be expanded to `__divsf3` call.

Similarly for your case i32 Multiplication will be expanded to `__mulsi3` function in **glibc**.

- Check all such libcalls in `lib/CodeGen/TargetLoweringBase.cpp` and `include/llvm/IR/RuntimeLibcalls.def`

Answer (score 0):

You can write an IR to IR transformation pass which replaces `mul` instructions by equivalent function call you propose. This way you wont have to change code generator.

Comment: I thought about using that solution, but it's definitely a hack because it seems that the appropriate place to put it is isn TargetLowering since that's what that stage is meant for.

There's even a built in fucntion for setOperationAction() with an option to specify LibCall, but I don't understand how to actually specify that function.